# Symfony workflow::can passes through workflow guard event listener

Tags: php, twig, workflow, symfony

I don't now if a lot of you have already tested the `symfony workflow` component but I hope some of you have :)

So, I am using this component on **two objects** and I want the **first object** to **update** the **second one** depending on the `transition` it is applying.

To do so, I am using the `workflow guard listener` on my **first object** and try to do a `workflow::apply` on my **second object (using the second workflow ...)**.

The problem is that, when I make a `workflow::can`, the event is **dispatched** and it tries to **apply** a new status on my **second object** ... This is quite not normal as I am just asking **if I can apply** some transition and **not** asking to **actually apply** it on my **first object**.

### config

```
framework:
    workflows:
        request_for_operation:
            type: 'state_machine'
            marking_store:
                type: 'single_state'
                arguments:
                    - 'status'
            supports:
                - AppBundle\Entity\RequestForOperation
            places:
                - draft
                - pending_for_management
                - in_progress
                - finished
                - canceled
            transitions:
                request_for_operations:
                    from: draft
                    to:   pending_for_management
                start_rfop_management:
                    from: pending_for_management
                    to:   in_progress
                close:
                    from: in_progress
                    to:   finished
                cancel:
                    from: [pending_for_management, in_progress]
                    to:   canceled
        operation:
            type: 'state_machine'
            marking_store:
                type: 'single_state'
                arguments:
                    - 'status'
            supports:
                - AppBundle\Entity\Operation
            places:
                - draft
                - pending_for_management
                - in_progress
                - finished
                - canceled
            transitions:
                validate_operation:
                    from: draft
                    to:   pending_for_management
                start_tracking:
                    from: pending_for_management
                    to:   in_progress
                close:
                    from: in_progress
                    to:   finished
                cancel:
                    from: [pending_for_management, in_progress]
                    to:   canceled
```

### Subscriber

```
class RequestForOperationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        OperationManager $operationManager,
        UserNotifier $userNotifier
    ) {
        $this->operationManager = $operationManager;
        $this->userNotifier = $userNotifier;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'workflow.request_for_operation.guard.request_for_operations' => ['onRequestForOperations'],
            'workflow.request_for_operation.guard.start_rfop_management' => ['onStartRfopManagement'],
            'workflow.request_for_operation.guard.close' => ['onClose'],
            'workflow.request_for_operation.guard.cancel' => ['onCancel'],
        ];
    }

    public function onRequestForOperations(GuardEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var RequestForOperation $rfop */
        $rfop = $event->getSubject();

        //get all the operations linked to the rfop
        $operations = $rfop->getOperations();
        foreach ($operations as $operation) {
            //set the status of the operation to 'pending_for_management'
            $this->operationManager->applyTransition($operation, 'validate_operation');
            //set the status of the sub-operations to 'pending_for_management'
            foreach ($operation->getChildren() as $subOperation) {
                $this->operationManager->applyTransition($subOperation, 'validate_operation');
            }

            //get the users (i.e: managers) linked to the operation and notify them (by mail or whatever)
            $this->notifyAssignedUsers($operation->getUsers(), $operation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I took the time to give a closer look at the Workflow class and I noticed that there are much more events dispatched than the documentation talks about ...

Comment: We have: leave, transition, enter, announce (and guard)

Comment: the guard event is dispatch on the workflow::can function, the others seems to be call on the workflow::apply (so maybe I have to use another event for what I want to do).

Comment: You are not supposed to apply something in a guard. The guard is just here to prevent using a transition based on some assertion

Comment: Wat is your question exactly? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

I think I encountered the same issue as you, and I have logged a bug with the Symfony project: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/33105